# Como cambiar de pagina haciendo clic en un gráfico, sin utilizar marcadores

Tags: powerbi

Estoy realizando unas practicas y se me ha solicitado que cuando una persona le de click en el grafico este se redirija a otra pagina, pero estoy teniendo un problema y es que no se como hacer ese tipo de cosas sin usar un botón.

Estuve investigando donde posiblemente una solución para mi problema seria usar marcadores donde cada uno guarde una pagina, pero vuelvo al problema inicial y es saber como cambiar de pagina cuando el usuario le de click al grafico y no a un botón,

Comment: Tal como lo planteas, no es posible. Pero si que mediante el botón contextual (aka botón derecho del ratón) puedes tener acceso a "Ver detalles" dirigiéndote a otra página. Aquí [tienes un documento](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough) de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Bien hablare con mi jefe de que no es posible hacer esas cosas de la forma en que lo planteo, te agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: disculpa tengo una pregunta, se puede hacer que se redirija a otro grafico es decir que si le doy click este se cambie a otro grafico?